# When I run engine.scala nothing happens

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, gatling

I'm using gatling and scala ans eclipse as an editor, when I click on Engine.scala to run it nothing happen, I dont know why ?
[image]

Comment: Try using the "Run" menu at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ScalaIDE](http://scala-ide.org/) (the Eclipse plugin for Scala) seems to be dead. You should either run from the command line with maven (`mvn gatling:test`) or switch to IntelliJ (that has great built-in support for Scala).

Comment: How to run Engine.scala ??

Comment: If you can't right click and select "Run as Scala", your IDE set up is broken. In particular, I don't think ScalaIDE supports Scala 2.13 which is the version Gatling 3.5 uses. As I said, Scala support on Eclipse is foobar and if you can't make it work, you'd better switch to an actively maintained IDE such as IntelliJ or run Gatling from the command line.

Comment: ScalaIDE IS dead. At some point burden of supporting it was moved to VirtusLab (they did it because customers), but at some point their customers told them _why bother, all the devs use IntelliJ_, so they stopped supporting Scala IDE and it virtually died. Later on VL started supporting some more promising solution (initiated by Scala Center) that now is gaining users instead of loosing it - Scala Metals. If you are not IntelliJ guy, try Scala Metals. It makes use of devs from software houses while isn't entirely dependent on them so it won't die anytime soon.

Comment: I agree Metals looks very promising. Yet, the user base is smaller than IntelliJ's. Then,  we haven't yet documented how to use Gatling with Metals (have a look at https://www.james-willett.com/gatling-vscode/). And finally I feel like the maven integration is brittle (the Bloop integration with scala-maven-plugin is an ugly hack). So I would rephrase Mateusz' suggestion. If VS Code is dominant in your organization, go with it as you'll get more support from your co-workers. Otherwise, go with IntelliJ, you'll get more support from the Gatling community (https://groups.google.com/g/gatling).